# Number of paths of a directed graph with a point set $V = \{1,\ldots, n\}$

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, proof-writing, induction

> Suppose a *directed* graph with point set $V= \{1,2,3, \ldots, n\}$ such that there is an edge from each vertex $i$ to each vertex $j \Leftrightarrow i \lt j$. 
>   How many directed paths are there from $1$ to $n$? Figure out a pattern and prove it.

I've looked at the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397357/find-a-recurrence-to-count-paths-in-a-directed-graph) but it has some other conditions.

So, what I've got so far are the cases from 0 till 6.

I've tried drawing the paths on one straight line from points $\{ i, \ldots , n\}$ and using a $n$- polygon. The cases from 1 and 2 are trivial which has resp.  0 and 1 direct path(s)( unless you consider for case 1 that it has 1 directed path of length 0 but I'm excluding that). For case 3 I found 2 directed paths, for 4 there are 4, for 5 it is 7 I think and for 6 there are 11 paths.

So if you take the difference of the number of paths of each case you'll get the sequence of the natural numbers.

So I need to prove the sequence of the natural numbers by induction? This seems weird and too easy? I think I have made a mistake.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi:\{2,3, \ldots n-2\} \mapsto \{0,1\}$ be a function. Then I can define a path going from $1$ to $n$ going through the vertices $i$ with $\phi(i)=1$. Similarly, given a path going from $1$ to $n$ I can define a function $\theta:\{2,3, \ldots n-2 \} $ given by $\theta(i)=1$ if the path goes through the vertex $i$ and $\theta(i)=0$ otherwise. Therefore we have a bijection between the number of paths with the required property and the number of functions from $\{2,3, \ldots n-2\}$ to $\{0,1\}$ which is $2^{n-2}$.

Comment: Why don't you use $1$, $n -1 $ and $n$ in the functions $\phi$ and $\theta$ ?

Comment: One of the conditions is that the paths must go from vertex 1 to vertex $n$.

Comment: Yeah but why isn't it $\phi : \{1,2,\ldots, n\} \mapsto \{0,1\}$ then you'll get directly $2^n$?

Comment: The condition that the paths must go from vertex 1 to $n$ is the same as saying you must have $\phi(1)=\phi(n)=1$.

Comment: I really want to accept your answer but I still don't fully understand your proof. I'll come back later after revising the chapter of functions and relations. Maybe I'll understand it better.

Comment: How would you prove this with induction? Just $2^{k-1}=2^{k-2}  + 2 \Rightarrow 2^{k-1}= 2^{k-1} $?

Answer (score 1):

Any path from $1$ to $n$ can have "intermediate stops" at certain of the points $2$, $3$, $\ldots$, $n-1$. In how many ways can you choose these intermediate stops?

Comment: So for$n = 3$ there is $1$ stop, from $1$ till $n$ there need to be $n-2$ intermediate stops I would say.

Comment: Did I say it wrong?

Comment: There indeed are $n-2$ stops to choose from.